# How to serial-over-lan past "Loading initial ramdisk"?

Tags: linux, kernel, console, ipmi, serial

I'd like to use "ipmitool ... sol activate" to record any kernel panics that may happen. I managed to keep GRUB2 in text-mode with "GRUB_TERMINAL=console" in /etc/default/grub. But right after the message "Loading initial ramdisk" (which is still GRUB), when Linux starts printing text on VGA console, messages on the serial console stop.

I guess either GRUB or Linux is doing *something* at that point, like loading a font, which kills off the vga-text-to-serial line. I'd like to keep it from doing that, whatever it is.

I have tried so far:

- Kernel options "nofb nomodeset text" (the latter being for other Distros, I think).
- GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text

One obvious alternative is to setup serial console redirection to the virtual COM port, which should make panics appear on the serial-over-lan as well, but I'd prefer to stay in the initial text-mode, so VGA and console are in sync and both accept input.

Answer (score 1):

By default kernel does not output anything to serial ports. You should explictly mention it.
To solve this add following to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

```
console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600n8
```

replace `9600n8` with your `sol` console settings.

Comment: This is the obvious alternative I mentioned and what I actually do right now. But what I want is stop the kernel from cutting off the vga-to-serial conversion (which would be the only way to accept input at both places, virtual-serial and physical-vga access). I think the BIOS stops vga-to-serial as soon as the virtual serial port gets activated by the OS in some way ... perhaps I need to blacklist serial?